# Nested AJAX Calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

in first ajax call server returns a json string that is converted to js array. I want to run an ajax call for each element of array.

For example, first ajax call returns semester 1,2,3,4. Now i want to retrieve subjects for semester 1 and show them in a table, then retrieve subjects of semester 2 and show all subjects in a table and so on...

I wrote a code but it shows all subjects in last table. Can some one help me?

```
$.ajax(
       {
           type: "POST",
           url: "returnSemesterNumbers",
           data: "programId="+selectedprog,
           success: function(data)
           {
                var semesters=$.parseJSON(data);
                for(x in semesters)
                {
                    semnum=semesters[x].semesterNumber;
                    alert(semnum);
                    $("#tables").append('<table id=table'+x+' style=float:left><tr><td>'+semnum+'</td></tr>');
                    $.ajax(
                           {
                               type: "POST",
                               url: "returnCourses",
                               data: "programId="+selectedprog+"&semNum="+semnum,
                               success: function(data1)
                               {
                                   var courses=$.parseJSON(data1);
                                    for(y in courses)
                                    {
                                        $("#table"+x).append('<tr><td>'+courses[y].title+'</td></tr>');
                                    }
                               }
                             });
                    $("#table"+x).append('</table>');
                    }
               }
             });
            }
            else
            {
                $("#tables").css('display','none');
            }
});
```

Comment: If you add `dataType: 'json'`, you won't need to `$.parseJSON(data)`.  `data` will be parsed for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The callback in your inner ajax call captures the `x` variable by reference.

Since all of the callbacks run after the loop, they all get the current value of `x`, which is the last element in the set.

You need to move the code in the loop into a separate function that takes `x` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of variable `x` might also cause issues.

Instead of:

```
for(x in semesters)
```

try:

```
for(var x in semesters)
```

Which will declare x as a variable in the scope of your first success ajax function, rather than as a global that can be changed by any other code (including jQuery).

Comment: This will not help.  (There will still only be one `x` variable)

Comment: The OP is calling a library function which could modify the global `x` before the second ajax query returns. That it doesn't is no guarantee that it won't. By adding the `var`, this possibility is avoided.

Comment: That is unlikely (although you are right; he should use `var`).  The real problem is reuse; see my answer.

Comment: GUS's method didn't work for me..after using that method all the data was going in first table..