# How to call one ajax inside other ajax in a chained manner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

How to call multiple ajax calls one after another in a chained way?

Hi,

I am having a controller method which returns json based on the start limit and end limit which needs to done by ajax call.

So, initially in first ajax call start limit =1 and end limit=100 and on success of this ajax, same ajax call should be called with updated start limit =101 and end limit=200.

Like wise multiple ajax reuqests needs to be sent till actual dead line of 1000 i reached.

So totatlly 10 ajax calls from 1-100,101-200,201-300 e.t.c till 1000 have to be sent.

Actually i am sending these chained ajax;s this way,

```
$.ajax({
                    url: getdata/100/200",
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    global: false,
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    async: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        json=JSON.stringify(data);
                        console.log("json" + json);
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                        if(json != null && json != "") {


    //some logic

    //2nd ajax 

    $.ajax({
                    url: getdata/101/201",
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    global: false,
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    async: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        json=JSON.stringify(data);
                        console.log("json" + json);
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                        if(json != null && json != "") {


    //some logic

//3rd ajax
    $.ajax({
                    url: getdata/201/301",
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    global: false,
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    async: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        json=JSON.stringify(data);
                        console.log("json" + json);
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                        if(json != null && json != "") {



}


}
```

But all the time only my first ajax is getting success and rest of the ajax;s are not getting executed and giving 404 error.

Is there any timeinterval needs to be set for calling one ajax inside?

What is the mistake i am doing here..?

can anyone help me in this issue?

Thanks

Comment: you can find solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892771/nested-ajax-calls

Comment: @DipaliVasani If OP is already using jQuery, you can do this much, much more easily with promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve these issue by using function like following :-

```
    // Make initial call to function with your data
    myAjaxCall(data, 1, 100);

    function myAjaxCall(data, startLimit, endLimit)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "getdata/"+startLimit+"/"+endLimit, // Concat variables as per your codes
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            global: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                json=JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log("json" + json);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                if(json != null && json != "") {
                    myAjaxCall(data, endLimit+1, endLimit+100);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to chain Ajax call try to use [Jquery.Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/)

it will looks like:

```
$.when($.ajax(...)).then($.ajax(..)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by recursive function

```
function ajaxRun(data){
    $.ajax({
        url: "getdata/201/301",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        global: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        async: false,
        success: function(resultData) {
            json=JSON.stringify(resultData);
            console.log("json" + json);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(resultData));
            if(json != null && json != "") {
                ajaxRun(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello change your parameter name every ajax success method like

```
success: function(resultData)
```

second time

```
success: function(secondresultData)
```